# How to handle multiple checkboxes with same v-model in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

It will be very helpful for me if anyone shows me about **sending and retrieving multiple checkbox value** to backend from vue.js. I searched for it through the internet but hardly found anything.

What I need is suppose I have a category and there are many books under that category. In my books table in database there are 20 books and I want to assign 10 books from within 20 books under a certain category from admin panel by using checkboxes in vue.js.

Also I have to retrieve them and show as checked for a certain category. For now I only know that I am going to use an array as v-model and use axios to send them and retrieve them.

```
`<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group" v-for="(book, index) in books" :key="index">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected_books" id="">
                <label for="">{{ book.name }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" @change="image" id="">
            </div>
            <button @click="save" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            books: [],
            selected_books: [],
            image: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        save: function () {
            let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("images", this.thumbnail);
            
            axios
                .post('/admin/store', fd)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.success = response.data.message;
                });
        },
    }
}
</script>`
```

So how should I take those checkboxes in the array **selected_books** and append them using formdata for the certain category. Besides how to fetch them and show as checked for that book category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `is_selected` type of flag for each individual book for your `v-model`

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group" v-for="(book, index) in books" :key="index">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="book.is_selected" id="">
                <label for="">{{ book.name }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" @change="image" id="">
            </div>
            <button @click="save" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Fetch your books in the mounted lifecycle hook using `fetch` or `axios`. Use the computed property for the `selected_books` array to filter all the books and return only the ones that have `is_selected` set to `true`.

```
<script>
export default {
    async mounted () {
       this.books = await fetch(`https://url.goes.here`, { method: `get` });
    },
    computed: {
        selected_books: function () {
            return this.books.filter(book => book.is_selected);
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            books: [],
            image: ``
        }
    },
    methods: {
        save: function () {
            let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append(`images`, this.thumbnail);
            
            axios
                .post(`/admin/store`, fd)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.success = response.data.message;
                });
        },
    }
}
</script>
```